# Share menu Mail option missing in OSX Big Sur

Tags: macos-bigsur

Just updated to Big Sur and can no longer share items (like PDFs) to Mail.app. As the screenshot shows, the option for Mail is greyed out and the icon shows Brave Browser. I have tried setting Safari as default and restarting to no effect.

[Options when trying to share object with mail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7xMP.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems another app replaced the default mail app. I've just met the problem with Chrome (gmail).

To fix it, open Mail, go to preferences, and set Mail as the default app.
The Share menu should show Mail now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I opened Mail and set email pref to Outlook which appears in the list. Closed Mail. Tried to share a link with Outlook, it worked. Reopened Mail and chosed Mail (not graded out anymore). Mail is now available to share. Ai
rDrop, Message... are all available.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely have this problem: share menu from safari no longer shows copy link as an option.

**Restore missing Share menu options** from
https://sixcolors.com/post/2016/05/quick-tip-restore-missing-share-menu-options/

OFFERS THIS TERMINAL COMMAND:

$$

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister
> -kill -seed

it may help someone but it does not fix my problem at all.